# Debugging Django request lifecycle

Tags: django, debugging, request

What's the first function Django executes after receiving a request?
I need to put a breakpoint just at the moment Django receives the request and observe the methods being called next, step by step.
For example, I call

`localhost:8000/test`

where do I insert the very first breakpoint to see how the middleware processes the request?